# Using an ArrayList to store the objects in another 2 Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist, copying

I have an assignment set that requires making a car
parking structure, I have so far made an Arraylist to store the Vehicles in, however I would like to make a Class for the parking spots and store them (with the vehicles) into an array of Zones (where the parking spaces are).

I guess my question is, how would I go about storing the Vehicle from the first Array with the parking spot in a separate Array? So the Array would have the ID of the parking spot and the car will be associated with that ID.

Comment: java.util.HashMap.  The key would be your vehicle id, the value would be the parking spot

Comment: Use **_HashMap_** to store the ID of the parking spot as key & Vehicles as values (in whatever way you're storing the values of Vehicle)!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to ***map*** the ID of each parking spot to a vehicle. As @Benson99 pointed out, a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) would do the trick.